# c++ MFC setting/appending text to a richedit control from a worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, text, mfc

from the main thread i can use member variables like so:

```
    CString updatetext;
    updatetext.Format(L"character length: %d\n", length );
    long nStart, nEnd;
    m_richeditcont.
    GetSel(nStart, nEnd);
    m_richeditcont.SetSel(nEnd, nEnd);
    m_richeditcont.ReplaceSel(updatetext);
```

however, without a worker thread the program would just hang. you can't use member variables from a worker thread, so how would i go about updating a richedit control with the text stored in updatetext from a worker thread?

i don't have any actual code, the code above is just an example, i just want to know how i would go about appending text stored in updatetext to a richedit control from a worker thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worker thread can send data over to the GUI thread using PostMessage or SendMessage. Then the GUI thread should be responsible for modifying the GUI. See FAQ 12 here:

http://vcfaq.mvps.org/mfc/index.htm

The worker thread should allocate the CString on the heap, then post the pointer in the lparam or wparam of the custom message. The GUI thread casts the pointer back to CString* and updates the control. Finally, the GUI thread deletes the CString from the heap.

Comment: +1 for *Finally, the GUI thread deletes the CString from the heap.* Totally important!!